# installing pgadmin after installing postgrsql app for mac

Tags: postgresql

I installed the postgresql app for mac on my  machine and wanted to use pgadmin as gui tool for it .Any guide on how to do this ?
Typing psql on the terminal opens the postgresql shell but with user mac .How can this be changed ?Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your question on pgadmin or psql?

Answer (score 0):

Writing

> how to install pgadmin on a mac

to Google you get page https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/

On that page you find instruction

> These packages are macOS appbundles. To install, mount the disk image using the finder, and drag the pgAdmin 4 appbundle to the desired location.